# Не меняются права доступа к файлам

Tags: linux, права, chmod, chown

Веселье с правами в линуксе, хех

В виртуалке (VirtualBox) запущена Ubuntu 16; хост-система Windows 10.

В `/mnt/lm-shara` примонтирована общая с виндой папка (NTFS). Раньше сразу после монтирования удавалось полноценно использовать общие файлы с обеих сторон, поэтому к настройкам прав не притрагивался. Сегодня в какой-то момент попытался отредактировать файл в общей папке и получил серию сообщений об ошибках доступа при сохранении.

У всех файлов каким-то образом оказался установлен владелец root.

Далее консоль (на примере одной подпапки, но с остальными ситуация аналогичная).

До `chown`:

```
$ ll /mnt/lm-shara/siemens_logo/examples/
итого 5024
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  12288 июля   5 13:51 ./
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  12288 июля   5 14:56 ../
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  64950 февр. 10 00:13 Air-conditioning system.lsc*
```

Попытка смены владельца:

```
$ sudo chown -vR username /mnt/lm-shara/siemens_logo/examples/
изменён владелец «lm-shara/siemens_logo/examples/Air-conditioning system.lsc» с root на username
```

То есть лог от `chown` подтверждает успешную смену владельца.
Проверка:

```
$ ll /mnt/lm-shara/siemens_logo/examples/
итого 5024
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  12288 июля   5 13:51 ./
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  12288 июля   5 14:56 ../
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  64950 февр. 10 00:13 Air-conditioning system.lsc*
```

Идентично! С `chmod` ситуация та же. И я до сих пор не могу изменять напрямую файлы в общей папке, но могу их туда-сюда таскать /фактически писать/.

Что могло произойти?

UPD:

```
$ cat /proc/mounts | grep lm-shara
lm-shara /mnt/lm-shara vboxsf rw,nodev,relatime 0 0
```

Comment: Вы не правильно понимаете суть происходящего. Нельзя поменять владельца для 1) NTFS - это не POSIX (NIX*) файловая система, соответственно права/владелец в понимании linux она не поддерживает 2) она подмонтирована. Это значит, что то что прописано `root` - это не совсем то, что вы подразумеваете. Нужно перемонтировать эту файловую систему. Допишите в вопрос  выхлоп `cat /proc/mounts | grep lm-shara`

Comment: Не трогал раньше права именно потому, что не совсем понимал, как *ix работает с NTFS, а при этом все работало. Информацию из /proc/mounts добавил.

Comment: Покажите `groups` и `cat /etc/group | grep vboxsf`

Comment: @TotalPusher, отучайтесь от *useless use of cat* и ему подобных.

Comment: Нда... проблема оказалась в VirtualBox или в редакторе gedit, который уже почти 10 лет (если верить форумам) по неизвестной и никем не выясняемой причине отказывается работать с расшаренными файлами VirtualBox. Способы исправить ситуацию не найдены; просто либо пользоваться другим редактором, либо таскать файл для редактирования в отдельную директорию.

Comment: @Luna в вопросе вообще ни слова какого результата вы хотели получить... оказалось прочесть файл в ВМ на сетивом разделе NTFS. Советую добавить это в вопрос.